# SQL Server Update wrong of date time when update entire table through cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cursor

I have a procedure shown below. When it runs on the entire table, it updates wrong value 'EndDate' '2019-11-29 10:16:50.000'.

I have used print command to see if value is right or not it prints 'Nov 28 2019  4:14PM' .

But when I change code to run on specific ItemId It Updates Right value '2019-11-28 16:14:38.000'.

Can anybody explain what is happening when I run code on entire table?

```
DECLARE @up_InvItemId INT = 14330

TRUNCATE TABLE InvPrice_History 

--DELETE FROM InvPrice_History where InvItemId=@up_InvItemId 


DECLARE stockCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT
        Id, InvItemId, LocationId, IsDeleted, Quantity, CreatedOn, StandardCost 
    FROM
        InvStockMoves  
    --WHERE InvItemId = @up_InvItemId ;

DECLARE @Id INT, @InvItemId INT, @LocationId INT, 
        @IsDeleted BIT, @Quantity FLOAT, @CreatedOn DATETIME, @StandardCost FLOAT;

DECLARE @pId INT, @pInvItemId INT, @pLocationId INT,
        @pStartDate DATETIME, @pEndDate DATETIME, @pCost FLOAT;

DECLARE @sId INT, @sInvItemId INT, @sLocationId INT, @sIsDeleted BIT,
        @sQuantity FLOAT, @sCreatedOn DATETIME, @sStandardCost FLOAT;

OPEN stockCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM stockCursor INTO @Id, @InvItemId, @LocationId, @IsDeleted, @Quantity, @CreatedOn, @StandardCost;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 
    SELECT TOP 1  
        @pId = Id, @pInvItemId = InvItemId,
        @pStartDate = StartDate, @pEndDate = EndDate,
        @pCost = Cost 
    FROM
        InvPrice_History
    WHERE
        InvItemId = @InvItemId 
    ORDER BY 
        StartDate DESC

    SET @sStandardCost = dbo.getByTimeCostInvItem(@CreatedOn, @InvItemId);

    IF @sStandardCost IS NOT NULL AND @sStandardCost > 0 
    BEGIN
        IF @pCost != @sStandardCost 
        BEGIN
            IF @InvItemId = @up_InvItemId 
            BEGIN
                PRINT(@CreatedOn);          
            END

            UPDATE InvPrice_History 
            SET EndDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @CreatedOn) 
            WHERE Id = @pId;
        END

        IF @pId IS NULL OR (@pId IS NOT NULL AND @pCost != @sStandardCost)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO InvPrice_History (InvItemId, StartDate, EndDate, Cost)
            VALUES (@InvItemId, @CreatedOn, NULL, @sStandardCost);
        END
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM stockCursor INTO @Id, @InvItemId, @LocationId, @IsDeleted, @Quantity, @CreatedOn, @StandardCost;
END

CLOSE stockCursor 
DEALLOCATE stockCursor
```

Comment: The fact that you are using a `CURSOR` smells like a large design flaw. You also have a user scalar function in there, which are notoriously slow. Personally I think you would be better off showing us your sample data, and expected results, and we can likely show you a far better, and efficient method to achieve your goal.

Comment: I Just fixed the issue Some how "@pId" does not update with the set query . By setting set @pId=null Before fetch next statement solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think when you use just print, the date argument gets converted to String.  See examples below:

```
1. begin print getdate() end
 2. select cast(getdate() as varchar)
```

Hence in your update you may have to use cast/convert to convert the date values in a specific format.